# How to extract a list of column values from a CSV file without using a pandas dataframe

Tags: python, csv, amazon-s3

So, my end objective is to integrate this Code in AWS Lambda, hence I want to avoid using pandas if possible. Here is how I am reading the CSV file (from S3):

```
import boto3
s3 = boto3.client('s3')
    
bucket_name = #getting the bucket name
file_key = #getting the file key

obj = s3.get_object(Bucket=bucket_name, Key=file_key)
```

Now how do I use `obj` (which is basically a .csv file) to get a list that contains all values in `col1` column of the csv?

Comment: Consider using the `csv` module from the standard library. That is what it is for.

Answer (score 0):

Try the below (just replace f.read() with reading from s3)

```
with open('Names.csv') as f:
    col1 = []
    obj = f.read()  # TODO read from s3
    lines = obj.split('\n')[1:]
    for line in lines:
        x = line.split(',')[0]
        if x:
            col1.append(x)
print(col1)
```

Names.csv

```
No,Name,Country
1,Alex,['India']
2,Ben,['USA']
11,Alex12,"['India', 'Italy']"
```

output

```
['1', '2', '11']
```